# Is there a better way to assign ipcRenerer reply event argument to a global variable?

Tags: reactjs, redux, electron, electron-builder

My global variable **rData** returns undefined

```
    let rData: any;
  await window.electron.ipcRenderer.readData('get_from_storage', network, addr);
  await window.electron.ipcRenderer.getResponse(
    'get_from_storage',
    (arg: any) => {
      rData = arg;
    }
  );
  console.log(rData);
```

This is the implementation in the preload.ts file

```
getResponse(channel: GetFromStorage, func: (...args: unknown[]) => void) {
      ipcRenderer.once(channel, (_event, ...args) => func(...args));
    },
readData(channel: GetFromStorage, network: any, address: any) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, network, address);
    },
```

Comment: Please show us how you've implemented the IPC functions in your preload by [edit]ing your question. Thanks!